# Laravel query building

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this query with left join which is return data in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM `items`
LEFT JOIN countries ON items.category_id = countries.id
where items.id = 20
```

I'm trying to reproduce it in Laravel like this

```
    $defaultCountry = DB::table('items')
                ->leftJoin('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'items.country_id')
                ->where('items.id', 20)
                ->select('items.*', 'countries.*')
                ->get();
```

but when I executed it I've got error

> Trying to get property of non-object ... line 6

Line 6 has

```
{!! $defaultCountry->symbol !!}
```

symbol is symbol of `defaultCountry` which is in table `countries`

When I do `var_dump($defaultCountry)` I'm see all data is in variable. Why I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to access to a object variable  on a collection, in case you want only to get one register you can swap `get()` for `first()`:

```
  $defaultCountry = DB::table('items')
                ->leftJoin('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'items.country_id')
                ->where('items.id', 20)
                ->select('items.*', 'countries.*')
                ->first();
```

Then you can access to the variable because now is not a collection of results.

In the case you want to access to the collection data in your view, you should loop the results with one `foreach` or `for` on your blade view:

```
@foreach($defaultCountry as $country)
    {!! $country->symbol !!}
@endforeach
```

Comment: So simple. Thank you very much! First will work fine. I don't have another symbol to show so it's first() only. I will accept the answer as soon as SO allow me.